# Making shapefile from Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, shapefile, pandas

I´d like to construct a shapefile from a Pandas Data Frame using the lon & lat rows.

I have got a csv file and I process it with pandas to make a data frame which is easier to handle

Is it posible to do that without make a loop line by line ?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, that can be done with `shapely` and `geopandas`.

Supposed that your pandas dataframe kind of looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
        {'some_attribute': 'abc', 'lat': '50.1234', 'lon': '10.4023'},
        {'some_attribute': 'def', 'lat': '40.5678', 'lon': '8.3365'},
        {'some_attribute': 'ghi', 'lat': '60.9012', 'lon': '6.2541'},
        {'some_attribute': 'jkl', 'lat': '45.3456', 'lon': '12.5478'},
        {'some_attribute': 'mno', 'lat': '35.7890', 'lon': '14.3957'},
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

=>

       lat      lon some_attribute
0  50.1234  10.4023            abc
1  40.5678   8.3365            def
2  60.9012   6.2541            ghi
3  45.3456  12.5478            jkl
4  35.7890  14.3957            mno
```

First, make sure that `geopandas` and `shapely` are installed properly which sometimes is not easy because they come with some dependencies (e.g. GEOS and GDAL). If does not work at first try via `pip install geopandas shapely`, search for the error on Google or StackOverflow/Gis.Stackexchange because most probably there will be an answer available solving that problem for you.

Then, it is just a matter of creating a new geometry column in your dataframe which combines the lat and lon values into a `shapely Point()` object. Note that the `Point()` constructor expects a tuple of float values, so conversion must be included if the dataframe's column dtypes are not already set to `float`.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

# combine lat and lon column to a shapely Point() object
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda x: Point((float(x.lon), float(x.lat))), axis=1)
```

Now, convert the pandas DataFrame into a `GeoDataFrame`. The geopandas constructor expects a geometry column which can consist of shapely geometry objects, so the column we created is just fine:

```
import geopandas
df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
```

To dump this GeoDataFrame into a shapefile, use geopandas' `to_file()` method (other drivers supported by [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) such as `GeoJSON` should also work):

```
df.to_file('MyGeometries.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

And that is what the resulting shapefile looks like when visualized with [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/):

[image: Resulting shapefile]

Comment: Hi, I have a similar situation,but instead of points, I have polygons. It is possible to do something similar df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda x: Point((float(x.lon), float(x.lat))), axis=1) but with polygons?

Answer (score 7):

**For ArcMap you need to define the Projection before exporting to Shapefile.**

```
import geopandas
df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')

# proj WGS84

df.crs= "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

df.to_file('MyGeometries.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: I did something similar, using `df.crs= "+init=epsg:27700"` to project my shapefile according to the British National Grid. However, when I open it in ArcGIS, the coordinate system is unknown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't done so already, install GeoPandas (e.g. one of either `pip install geopandas` or `conda install geopandas` for Anaconda/Miniconda users).

Here is how to read a CSV file with pandas, then use the [`geopandas.points_from_xy`](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) helper function to create a geometry column, then write a shapefile:

```
import pandas
import geopandas

from io import StringIO

# example CSV file
csv_input = StringIO("""\
Name,Lat,Long
Kingston,18,-76.8
Lima,-12.05,-77.05
Reykjavik,64.15,-21.95
""")

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(pandas.read_csv(csv_input))
gdf.set_geometry(
    geopandas.points_from_xy(gdf['Long'], gdf['Lat']),
    inplace=True, crs='EPSG:4326')
gdf.drop(['Lat', 'Long'], axis=1, inplace=True)  # optional
gdf.to_file('some_capitals.shp')
```

Comment: Definitely faster!
same data: - this method " 56.2 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop " vs  accepted answer + assign crs "1.75 s ± 41.6 ms per loop "